# CSP problem using ajax to execute javascript from an HTTP Request

Tags: ajax, firefox, content-security-policy

Using 'strict-dynamic' works with CHROME but not with FIREFOX.

With FIREFOX:

- with 'self' only my script files are loaded. But the javascript code from ajax is refused.
- with 'strict-dynamic' my script files are refused, on the pretext that none of the sha384 hashes of the integrity attribute correspond to the content of the sub-resource !!???

my php code. I should see "javascript yes!!!!!!!!!!!!" in the console. It's ok with chrome. Firefox refuses and does not load me jquery

```php
<?
header("Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'sha384-I7/UTpkJas2maMjJpGmrvEgQecqO8Dta/9Wwh+cQrH6Jj984WRRFhWg4MV/oTkIW' 'nonce-0006c7f26c'; ", true);

if(isset($_GET["ajx"]))
{
    ?>
    YES
    <script>
        console.log('javascript yes !!!!!!!!!!!')
    </script>
    <?
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../public/plugins/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7/UTpkJas2maMjJpGmrvEgQecqO8Dta/9Wwh+cQrH6Jj984WRRFhWg4MV/oTkIW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    body <div id="zz"></div>
    <script nonce=0006c7f26c>
    console.log('yes')

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'/public/testCSP.php?ajx=1',
        async:false,

        success : function(response, statut)
        {
            if(response)
            {
                    $('#zz').html(response);
            }
        },
        error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){ if(erreur) alert("Erreur  : "+erreur)},
        complete : function(resultat, statut){   }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```